# unable to start nodejs app- Error: npm.load() required

Tags: node.js

whenever I am starting my Node app it's giving following error.

```
Error: Failed to replace env in config: ${NPM_TOKEN}
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/config/core.js:429:13
at String.replace (native)
at envReplace (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/config/core.js:424:12)
at parseField (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/config/core.js:400:7)
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/config/core.js:338:17
at Array.forEach (native)
at Conf.add (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/config/core.js:337:23)
at ConfigChain.addString (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/config-chain/index.js:244:8)
at Conf.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/config/core.js:325:10)
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:78:16



/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/npm.js:29
throw new Error('npm.load() required')
^

Error: npm.load() required
at Object.npm.config.get (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/npm.js:29:11)
at exit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/error-handler.js:58:40)
at process.errorHandler (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/error-handler.js:387:3)
at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
at process.emit (events.js:169:7)
at process._fatalException (node.js:224:26)
```

Plz provide any solution. I totally stucked with this.Due to this issue I am unable to start my app and complete my work.

Comment: For me it was because of private packages I had and did not configure NPM_TOKEN env var

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NPM - Failed to replace env in config: ${NPM\_TOKEN}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52015748/npm-failed-to-replace-env-in-config-npm-token)

Answer (score 0):

- Temporary remove file `.npmrc` with your ${NPM_TOKEN}
- Switch to proper node version ( with node version manager you can run like `nvm use 12` )
- export your environment variable "export NPM_TOKEN=yourvalue"
- move back your `.npmrc` file and try to run your project again!

Comment: Only running this `export NPM_TOKEN=yourvalue` command fixed this issue for me. Thank you.

Comment: Temporarily @NidhiShah . Add that script to your bash or z rc file for future use.