# NPM - Failed to replace env in config: ${NPM_TOKEN}

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, node-modules

I am trying to build a react app, but when I execute the command `npm -i` it gives me the following error:

```
Error: Failed to replace env in config: ${NPM_TOKEN}
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/config/core.js:415:13
    at String.replace (<anonymous>)
    at envReplace (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/config/core.js:411:12)
    at parseField (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/config/core.js:389:7)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/config/core.js:330:24
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Conf.add (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/config/core.js:328:23)
    at ConfigChain.addString (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/config-chain/index.js:244:8)
    at Conf.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/config/core.js:316:10)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:78:16
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/npm.js:61
      throw new Error('npm.load() required')
      ^

Error: npm.load() required
    at Object.get (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/npm.js:61:13)
    at process.errorHandler (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/error-handler.js:205:18)
    at process.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at process._fatalException (internal/bootstrap/node.js:448:27)
```

I am using MacOS High Sierra. I tried to set the NPM_TOKEN as an environment variable with following command:

```
set -x NPM_TOKEN = xyz
```

but it doesn't work.
What is the problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to replace env in config using Bash & NPM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35483721/failed-to-replace-env-in-config-using-bash-npm)

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem? I've followed all the instructions in all the linked questions etc and I got nothin

Comment: @JSilv see my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55610638/5922757

Comment: Here you can find my solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/67648863/14178236

Answer (score 110, accepted):

### First Possible Solution:

Simple Solution: `rm -f ./.npmrc` (Deleting a .npmrc file)

### Second Possible Solution:

However if you don't want to delete the file, you can simply remove this line of code in the `.npmrc` file.

Line of Code: `//registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken=${NPM_TOKEN}` (Remove this code)

#### Third Possible Solution

Worst case scenario:

- `nano ~/.bash_aliases` or `nano ~/.bash_profile`
- add `export NPM_TOKEN="XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX"`
- CTRL + X to exit
- Y to save

Comment: This is not a solution, but a workaround. A proper solution would be to remove this line and update your CI deployment configuration like `npm config set '//registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken' "${NPM_TOKEN}" && npm publish`.

Comment: I am missing the why of this solution, would have been nice to have it.

Comment: If you remove this line from the file how then do you gain access to the private repo?

Comment: Have to reiterate that the above is not a solution and the *worst case scenario* as it is described, is a viable solution in some circumstances.

Comment: You might need to set your NPM_TOKEN in your environment (e.g. .zprofile, .bashrc)

Comment: "Yeah, just delete the file or the line that causes problems"

Great solution! /s

Answer (score 118):

## Actually proper solution

Update your CI deployment configuration:

```bash
npm config set '//registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken' "${NPM_TOKEN}"
npm publish
```

Remove this line from the `.npmrc` file:

```
//registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken=${NPM_TOKEN}
```

### Example build config

You can see this solution used in practice in one of my GitHub repositories: https://github.com/Jezorko/lambda-simulator/blob/5882a5d738060c027b830bcc2d58824c5d27942b/.github/workflows/deploy.yml#L26-L27

The encrypted environment variable is an NPM token.

## Why the other "solutions" are mere workarounds

I've seen answers here and under [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35483721/failed-to-replace-env-in-config-using-bash-npm) that recommend simply removing the variable setting line or `.npmrc` file entirely.

**Thing is, the `.npmrc` file might not be ignored by your VCS system and modifying it might lead to accidental pushes to your project's repository. Additionally, the file may contain other important settings.**

The problem here is that `.npmrc` does not allow defaults when setting up environment variables. For example, if the following syntax was allowed, the issue would be non-existent:

`//registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken=${NPM_TOKEN:-undefined}`

Comment: Executing `npm config set '//registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken' "${NPM_TOKEN}"` threw the exact same error from title for me. Resolved only using the first workaround in the accepted answer.

Comment: This approach would leak "${NPM_TOKEN}" to any user on a machine able to list processes and their arguments, eg. with `ps`, `pgrep` etc.

Comment: added to Jenkinsfile and works like a charm! This is exactly what I was looking for! Cheers!

Comment: @WadeJensen If you are afraid of passing sensitive information as command parameters, perhaps your CI/CD environment is not secure enough. What you described would require constant monitoring of processes and their arguments, `npm config set` executes rather quickly for a human to catch the exact moment it runs. This implies you have a user with malicious intentions with access to your machine… Anyhow, you can use some other command to write token to npm config file (one that doesn't use command line args).

Comment: @alexlomba87 what are the contents of your `.npmrc` file? Perhaps you're setting literally `${NPM_TOKEN}` instead of an environment variable?

Comment: @Jezor a lot of developers work on multi-tenant internal systems which are behind corporate firewalls, but are loosely secured from internal users. You want your security model to be "crunchy everywhere", not "hard shell outside, soft-gooey inside".

Comment: @WadeJensen I think we are agreeing, then! Only few admin users should have access to CI/CD internals (SSH / admin), devs should only see pipeline results. Still, you can commit a test that just reads `.npmrc` and fetches the token - there's a certain point where adding more restrictions doesn't increase security anymore.

Comment: @funtik since this answer has received much support, could you please consider marking it as the accepted answer? The current accepted answer is quite misleading.

Comment: This answer should go to the top.

Comment: Good stuff, worked over here! Nice to not have to use that file.

Comment: this worked for me but every time I restart the computer I need to do it again. Any ideas why?

Comment: @kilinkis difficult to say without taking a look at your deployment script. Are you deploying from your machine instead of a CI server?

Comment: @Jezor is not a CI context, is just my machine and I'm trying to run stuff like `yarn storybook`, then get the error in the question, and by doing this proposed solution it works after, until the next restart. Now I export the key in my zhsrc and removed that line from .npmrc. We'll see how that works next time I restart.

Comment: @kilinkis locally you should keep the token in your user `.npmrc` file, `~/.npmrc` (:

Answer (score 57):

I have an easy solution to this issue. After you set your NPM_TOKEN globally into your environment then replace

```
//registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken=${NPM_TOKEN}
```

with

```
//registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken=$NPM_TOKEN
```

It's worked well for me on macOS Catalina.

Comment: This did fix running from command line (I'm macOS Catalina as well), however it did not work on a variety of CIs

Comment: I read that the recommended solution was just a "workaround", and even the second most recommended solution was insecure. I'm also running on macOS Catalina and your solution worked well for me. This seems the best solution, since it doesn't compromise security nor is it also just a temporary workaround.

Comment: Solved an issue I was having with `yarn` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70659269/vercel-deploy-of-my-nextjs-app-with-font-awesome-pro-is-returning-a-401-build-er

Comment: Could you explain why this works? Is it to do with the type of terminal you use?

Comment: @CharlieB If you're on Windows this might not be the best solution you're looking for. I use ITerm2 with Fish Shell on macOS.

Comment: I am on mac not windows.I don't really understand why removing the curly braces makes a difference. Is it bash related magic?

Answer (score 14):

If you just set your ~/.profile for the first time (OSX, Ubuntu) and added this line: export NPM_TOKEN="XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX".
Then you must enter this line to the terminal afterward:

```
source ~/.profile
```

Comment: If you are using a private npm package, you also need to login using `npm login`, set your username, password, email, and OTP if required. Then after logging in you can run npm/yarn commands

Answer (score 7):

Running `npm install` in an IDE (like WebStorm) was my problem. I added the NPM_TOKEN environment variable to `.bash_profile` and restarted my Terminal, but not my IDE! The IDE did not pick up the changes to the environment until I restarted it as well.

Comment: From my understanding, terminal tabs/windows just run/parse bash_profile on start, meaning any changes to the files need to be run `source ~/.bash_profile` in existing windows/tabs in order for it to be re-parsed. Whenever I change the file, I can, from VSCode terminal, run source and it'll reinitialize with the new one, not needing to actually kill the IDE.

Comment: Ok so NPM_TOKEN needed to be in the terminal's environment. Thanks, I got my setup in Docker through this error too by adding NPM_TOKEN to `services.serviceName.environment`

Answer (score 3):

The following worked for me. I had to place

```
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion
```

AFTER the line where i specify

```
export NPM_TOKEN='mytoken'
```

Answer (score 3):

I fixed this via passing a docker build arg as

```
ARG NPM_TOKEN
ENV NPM_TOKEN=$NPM_TOKEN
ENV NPM_CONFIG_TOKEN=$NPM_TOKEN
```

My scoped registry line with `authToken` wasn't being read properly inside my docker container. When running inside the container and invoking `npm config list` is didn't register.

So setting this variable : `NPM_CONFIG_TOKEN` and running `npm config list` registers it under a `token` key in the config.

Answer (score 2):

Im my case moving the export of the token inside my `.zsh` (or `.bash_profile`) **to the top of the file** fixed the problem because it has been initialised too late before.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed it by setting `NPM_TOKEN=""`

In github action, i set the `env:`

```yaml
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
      NPM_TOKEN: ""
    # ....
```

Answer (score 1):

https://www.runoob.com/linux/linux-shell-variable.html
replace

```
'//registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken=${NPM_TOKEN}'
```

with

```
'//registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken='${NPM_TOKEN}
```

Answer (score 1):

I got this issue while trying to setup a CI/CD job in Gitlab. I eventually found out that the error was caused because the variable that was throwing the error was set to a protected variable.

I changed it under Settings > CI / CD > Variables.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows while using git bash, setting a regular Windows environment variable worked for me. This answer helped [setting an environment variable in Git Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38385930/4455570)

Answer (score 0):

For people on Ubuntu coming from google:

- nano ~/.bash_aliases
- export NPM_TOKEN="PUT_YOUR_TOKEN_HERE"
- CTRL+X to exit
- Y to save

Answer (score 0):

I am also getting this problem but I find a solution when I am pushing my repo on Heroku so I notice that Heroku run the command react-script start or build

```
//registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken=${NPM_TOKEN}
```

so this syntax didn't give the error but when I use the same syntax in my system and run the command it gives me.
Because usually when we run in our system we use cmd npm or yarn but if you use react-script then it will not gives an error

Answer (score 0):

In case of **windows** and **visual studio code** - just **restart** your visual studio, it helps.

Also, **how to set this environment variable** on **windows**?

open Registry Editor, and follow `\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment`, and create there another one "string value" with your token or whatever you need.

Answer (score 0):

For mac

vim ~/.bash_profile

add `export NPM_TOKEN=XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX`

source ~/.bash_profile

also, add the below entry in the .zshrc file to apply the profile when a new terminal tab/window is opened.

```
if [ -f ~/.bash_profile ]; then
  . ~/.bash_profile
fi
```

Comment: This sets the same NPM_TOKEN for every project on your system.

Answer (score 0):

Using AWS CODEARTIFACT

If you use docker, you need to add this to your Dockerfile

```
...
ARG CODEARTIFACT_AUTH_TOKEN
...
RUN export CODEARTIFACT_AUTH_TOKEN=$CODEARTIFACT_AUTH_TOKEN
RUN npm i
...
```

This is the .npmrc file

```
registry=https://sidanmor-codeartifact-main-112233.d.codeartifact.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/npm/js-utils/
//https://sidanmor-codeartifact-main-112233.d.codeartifact.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/npm/js-utils/:always-auth=true
//https://sidanmor-codeartifact-main-112233.d.codeartifact.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/npm/js-utils/:_authToken=${CODEARTIFACT_AUTH_TOKEN}
registry=http://registry.npmjs.org
```

And the build command will be:

```
docker build --build-arg CODEARTIFACT_AUTH_TOKEN=xxxyyyzzz . --tag my-tag
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone using `npm-run-all` running into this issue that:

- Doesn't want to remove or modify their `.npmrc` file (because the syntax is actually ok)
- Doesn't want to add the variable in question into their shell profile
- Doesn't want to set the variable before every single script as `"build": "NPM_TOKEN=... ..."`

I found that when using `npm-run-all` any scripts using `run-p` or `run-s` that use other scripts (either directly or indirectly) that use the form `npm run <SCRIPT>` will parse the `.npmrc` configuration file, which in turn will cause errors if variables are not set.

To fix this, all you need to do is convert any scripts that are used, directly or indirectly by scripts using `run-s` or `run-p` to use `run-s`

Let's take this as an example:

```json
...
"scripts": {
    "dev": "run-s build*",
    "build:js": "...",
    "build:css": "...",
    "predev": "npm run clean",
    "clean": "rm -rf ./dist ./build"
}
...
```

Although this script does not call `predev` directly, it will be run before `dev` and this will cause configuration to be read, throwing the error

Instead, change it as follows:

```json
...
"scripts": {
    "dev": "run-s build*",
    "build:js": "...",
    "build:css": "...",
    "predev": "run-s clean",
    "clean": "rm -rf ./dist ./build"
}
...
```

where `predev` now uses `run-s` instead of `npm run`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on Macbook pro. Actually the issue is with the naming. Previously i added my token to my env file as below

```
export GITHUB_TOKEN="xxxx-xxxx-xxxx"
```

**Solved**

Solved by changing the name to

```
export GITHUB_ACCESS_TOKEN="xxxx-xxxx-xxxx"
```

**Conclution**

When you define access tokens it is better to name it as `**_ACCESS_TOKEN` so the npm can identify it correctly.

Answer (score -3):

you can also replace the `${NPM_TOKEN}` with your own GitHub generated personal token

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).