# How to set .npmrc from command line (build args)

Tags: javascript, heroku, npm, build

I need to configure my `.npmrc` but as a build argument.
I have found this how to do it on the official npm repo: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53714075:

```
npm config set '//registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken' "${TOKEN}" && npm publish
```

However, this is for Webix so my `.npmrc` looks like this:

```
@xbs:registry=http://npm.webix.com/
//npm.webix.com/:_authToken="${TOKEN}"
unsafe-perm=true
```

Can someone help me, how I configure this as build arg?

---

### Edit

Now I'm at this string, but it still fails, I guess I am doing something wrong?

```
npm config set @xbs:registry http://npm.webix.com/ && npm config set "unsafe-perm=true" && npm config set "//npm.webix.com/:_authToken=${TOKEN}" && npm publish
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue with this:

```
npm config set @scope:registry http://registry-url/ && npm config set //token-address "${NPM_AUTH_TOKEN}"
```