# NPM - Failed to replace env in config: ${NPM_BASE64_USERNAME_PASSWORD}

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm getting the error below whenever I try to execute anything in my terminal (e.g. `npm test` or `npm install`)

I've tried to follow steps similar laid out here - [NPM - Failed to replace env in config: ${NPM_TOKEN}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52015748/npm-failed-to-replace-env-in-config-npm-token). I've also tried setting my username and (encoded) password in my .npmrc file, none of which appear to work for me.

Not really sure what else I should try here ....

```
Error: Failed to replace env in config: ${NPM_BASE64_USERNAME_PASSWORD}
    at /Users/andrew.lee/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.1/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/config/core.js:415:13
    at String.replace (<anonymous>)
    at envReplace (/Users/andrew.lee/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.1/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/config/core.js:411:12)
    at parseField (/Users/andrew.lee/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.1/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/config/core.js:389:7)
    at /Users/andrew.lee/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.1/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/config/core.js:330:24
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Conf.add (/Users/andrew.lee/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.1/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/config/core.js:328:23)
    at ConfigChain.addString (/Users/andrew.lee/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.1/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/config-chain/index.js:244:8)
    at Conf.<anonymous> (/Users/andrew.lee/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.1/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/config/core.js:316:10)
    at /Users/andrew.lee/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.1/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:123:16
/Users/andrew.lee/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.1/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/npm.js:59
      throw new Error('npm.load() required')
      ^

Error: npm.load() required
    at Object.get (/Users/andrew.lee/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.1/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/npm.js:59:13)
    at process.errorHandler (/Users/andrew.lee/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.1/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/error-handler.js:208:32)
    at process.emit (events.js:375:28)
    at process._fatalException (internal/process/execution.js:163:25)
```

Answer (score -1):

Even, I had encounter the issue similar to thiis while pulling the node component from aws codeartifact via docker file. What you need to do is create a .nmprc file and drop it root location fo the npm installaiton, doing this your issue will get addressed. I was getting below exception while ruinnig npm install in docker file something like
Run powershell -command npm install or any anglar cli install via npm

"8 : RUN powershell -Command  npm install
2022-03-03T19:16:34.2653417Z  ---> Running in 97791ba93799
2022-03-03T19:16:44.2652033Z [91mError: Failed to replace env in config: ${env:CODEARTIFACT_AUTH_TOKEN}
2022-03-03T19:16:44.2652033Z     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:415:13
2022-03-03T19:16:44.2661894Z     at String.replace ()
2022-03-03T19:16:44.2661894Z     at envReplace (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:411:12)
2022-03-03T19:16:44.2661894Z     at parseField (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:389:7)
2022-03-03T19:16:44.2661894Z     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:330:24
2022-03-03T19:16:44.2661894Z     at Array.forEach ()
2022-03-03T19:16:44.2661894Z     at Conf.add (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:328:23)"

**Solution**
please use this docker file, I was passing token from build file something like

Build.ps1
$env:CODEARTIFACT_AUTH_TOKEN = aws codeartifact get-authorization-token --domain se2codepkg --domain-owner 590427636078  --query authorizationToken --output text

docker.ps1

Run powershell echo "registry=https://se2codepkg-590427636078.d.codeartifact.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/npm/npm-store/ 
//se2codepkg-590427636078.d.codeartifact.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/npm/npm-store/:always-auth=true 
//se2codepkg-590427636078.d.codeartifact.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/npm/npm-store/:_authToken=${env:CODEARTIFACT_AUTH_TOKEN}">.npmrc

I got the idea by going through below link
https://developpaper.com/question/after-nodejs-is-installed-successfully-npm-cannot-run-and-prompt-failed-to-replace-env-in-config/