# Vercel deploy of my NextJS app with Font Awesome Pro is returning a 401 build error

Tags: next.js, font-awesome, vercel

I am attempting to install Font Awesome Pro in my NextJS app, which is deployed via Vercel. However, I keep getting this error:

```
error An unexpected error occurred: "https://npm.fontawesome.com/@fortawesome/pro-light-svg-icons/-/5.15.4/pro-light-svg-icons-5.15.4.tgz: Request failed \"401 Unauthorized\""
```

Then the build exits with `Error: Command "yarn install" exited with 1`

Locally everything works great. I have the following in my .npmrc file:

```
@fortawesome:registry=https://npm.fontawesome.com/
//npm.fontawesome.com/:_authToken=NPM_RC
```

And then within Vercel settings I have an environmental variable with the name `NPM_RC` and the value is my personal **Pro-Token**.

As an aside: I tried doing a global setup using my token but that returns the same error mentioned above. When I reached out to Font Awesome they said that Global setups can be hit or miss and that I should try the `.npmrc` route.

I reached out to Font Awesome after giving the .npmrc route and try and still having the error. They are not sure what is going on... I am stuck and any help would be greatly appreciated. Cheers!

Comment: is it because you have @fortawesome instead of @fontawesome?

Comment: FYI - https://github.com/FortAwesome/react-fontawesome/issues/463

Comment: @LazarNikolic It is odd that they did that (fort awesome -- font awesome) I have wondered if it was an early typo they never fixed and it stuck or if they are planning on adding more services like Font Awesome to their fort.... ‍♂️ The docs do say that "fortawesome" is correct though  Good eye https://fontawesome.com/v5.15/how-to-use/on-the-web/setup/using-package-managers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I needed to update my .npmrc file with the following:

```
@fortawesome:registry=https://npm.fontawesome.com/
//npm.fontawesome.com/:_authToken=${NPM_RC}
```

Thank you @robmadole!

Comment: The solution had one issue - I kept getting the error: `error An unexpected error occurred: "Failed to replace env in config: ${NPM_RC}".` when running `yarn` commands. I read this article https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52015748/npm-failed-to-replace-env-in-config-npm-token and my solution was to remove {} from the NPM_RC...